# MS Access Combo Box Selection Implementation via text

Tags: string, ms-access, select, combobox, row

I want to simply select a row in a combo box based on a string value, not an index location.

I have a combo box with 3 columns, first column is an ID field, the other two are first name and last name respectively.

I have the ID field value ready when the box is ready, but do not know how to select it without making a stupid loop that checks each value one at a time.

Comment: Are you trying to hide the ID field so that you can select an item from the combo box by typing in a string? I'm not sure what you mean by your last statement, can you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both bound and unbound comboboxes, you can set the value to anything that matches the bound column and the appropriate line will be displayed.

```
 Row source : SELECT ID, Surname FROM Table
 Bound Column : 1
 Column count : 2
 Column Widths : 0,2
```

To set the combo:

```
 Me.MyCombo = 21
```

The surname from a record with ID 21 will be displayed in the combo.

To programmatically set the combo to one of the columns, you can use DlookUp for combos based on tables:

```
Me.MyCombo = DLookup("ID", "Table", "Surname='" & MyString & "'")
```

Comment: That is the function I was looking for. I do wish that DLookup would return an array for multiple matches. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99704

Comment: If multiple matches are a possibility, a combobox is not much use. You can use a listbox and an sql string: `Me.AListbox.RowSource="SELECT ID, AText FROM ATable WHERE AText = '" & Somevar & "'"`, or you can iterate through a recordset based on a similar sql string.